# Multiple maven pom.xml files

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have an Eclipse project with a GWT client and a Restlet API. I normally use Maven for dependency management but I havent used it in an Eclipse project where seperate parts have seperate dependencies. For example - the client would use Google Gin for dependency injection and the server uses Google Guice.

Am I able to split it into two seperate pom.xml files to manage the dependencies of both seperate areas?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a multi module project. See examples [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/reactor.html) and [here](http://blog.code-adept.com/2008/01/14/maven-multi-module-quickstart/) and [here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-create-a-multi-module-project-in-eclipse.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new pom like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Then in your original project just add:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>your-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```